# Is it possible run multiple tasks parallelly in one thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, multitasking

When creating a new Thread or Runnable in Java, are they the smallest unit of processing/computation environment one can create? Is it possible to run multiple tasks asynchronously within one Thread?

Comment: No. A Thread is the smallest multitasking unit. The CPU pipelines can process instructions in a semi asynchronous way, but they are still rendered sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, no. In order for two operations to execute in parallel, they must be in separate threads or processes.